Not getting the significance that is apparent from my barplot (and with Prism) with kruskal-wallis test, Dunn-test?
Someone plotted this data for me in prism using KW and Dunn's and I wanted to do it in R, but I'm getting way different R results. For instance, in prism there are sig differences between the control and treatments in all three facets. Also I'm getting an error of:
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in stat_signif().
Caused by error in kruskal.test.default():
! all observations are in the same group
2: Computation failed in stat_signif().
Caused by error in kruskal.test.default():
! all observations are in the same group
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(FSA)
library(rcompanion)



DTData <- read.csv("C:/Users/Coral HD/R/Amox/LiquidInhibition/LiquidInhib_ZeroAmox.csv")

data$Day <- as.factor(data$Day)
data$Treatment <- as.factor(data$Treatment)

# Create a faceted bar plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Treatment, y=CFUs, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day, scales="fixed") +
  labs(title="CFUs by Treatment across Different Days", y="Mean CFUs", x="Treatment") +
  theme_bw()
print(p)

# Perform Kruskal-Wallis Test by Day
kw_results <- data %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Kruskal_Wallis = kruskal.test(CFUs ~ Treatment)$p.value)

# Print Kruskal-Wallis results
print(kw_results)

# Perform Dunn's Test for multiple comparisons
dunn_results <- list()
for (day in unique(data$Day)) {
  subset_data <- data[data$Day == day,]
  dunn_test <- dunnTest(CFUs ~ Treatment, data = subset_data, method = "bonferroni")
  dunn_results[[as.character(day)]] <- dunn_test
}

# Print Dunn's Test results
print(dunn_results)

# Adding significance brackets
# Please note: Adjusting manually as per p-values might be necessary
p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "kruskal.test", 
                       comparisons = list(c("0", "100"), c("0", "400"), c("100", "400")), 
                       label.y = c(300, 400, 500)) 


structure(list(Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("1", "14", "28"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("0", "100", "400"), class = "factor"), 
    CFUs = c(138L, 148L, 141L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 348L, 
    290L, 321L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 250L, 215L, 218L, 28L, 
    45L, 34L, 35L, 41L, 28L)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")

Updated the code to fix DTData. Change to data. But my question still remains. Expecting to get

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(FSA)
library(rcompanion)



data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Coral HD/R/Amox/LiquidInhibition/LiquidInhib_ZeroAmox.csv")

data$Day <- as.factor(data$Day)
data$Treatment <- as.factor(data$Treatment)

# Create a faceted bar plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Treatment, y=CFUs, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day, scales="fixed") +
  labs(title="CFUs by Treatment across Different Days", y="Mean CFUs", x="Treatment") +
  theme_bw()
print(p)

# Perform Kruskal-Wallis Test by Day
kw_results <- data %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Kruskal_Wallis = kruskal.test(CFUs ~ Treatment)$p.value)

# Print Kruskal-Wallis results
print(kw_results)

# Perform Dunn's Test for multiple comparisons
dunn_results <- list()
for (day in unique(data$Day)) {
  subset_data <- data[data$Day == day,]
  dunn_test <- dunnTest(CFUs ~ Treatment, data = subset_data, method = "bonferroni")
  dunn_results[[as.character(day)]] <- dunn_test
}

# Print Dunn's Test results
print(dunn_results)

# Adding significance brackets
# Please note: Adjusting manually as per p-values might be necessary
p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "kruskal.test", 
                       comparisons = list(c("0", "100"), c("0", "400"), c("100", "400")), 
                       label.y = c(300, 400, 500))  # Adjust these y values as needed based on your plot scale



Getting Error
Here is the updated code using the custom Kruskal-Wallis function:
I get this Error:
Error in summarise():
ℹ In argument: Kruskal_Wallis = kruskal.test(CFUs ~ Treatment)$p.value.
ℹ In group 1: Day = 1.
Caused by error in kruskal.test():
! argument "y" is missing, with no default
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(FSA)
library(rcompanion)



data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Coral HD/R/Amox/LiquidInhibition/LiquidInhib_FortyAmox.csv")

View(data)

data$Day <- as.factor(data$Day)
data$Treatment <- as.factor(data$Treatment)

# Create a faceted bar plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Treatment, y=CFUs, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean, show.legend = FALSE, color = "black", width = 0.65) +
  facet_wrap(~ Day, scales="fixed") +
  ylim(0,550) +
  labs(title="", y="Mean CFUs", x="Treatment") +
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 11), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), 
        strip.text = element_text(size = 15))
print(p)

#Custom KW
kruskal.test <- function(x, y, paired = FALSE) {
  stats:::kruskal.test.default(x = c(x,y), g = rep(1:2, c(length(x), length(y))))
}


# Perform Kruskal-Wallis Test by Day
kw_results <- data %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Kruskal_Wallis = kruskal.test(CFUs ~ Treatment)$p.value)

# Print Kruskal-Wallis results
print(kw_results)

# Perform Dunn's Test for multiple comparisons
dunn_results <- list()
for (day in unique(data$Day)) {
  subset_data <- data[data$Day == day,]
  dunn_test <- dunnTest(CFUs ~ Treatment, data = subset_data, method = "bonferroni")
  dunn_results[[as.character(day)]] <- dunn_test
}

# Print Dunn's Test results
print(dunn_results)

# Adding significance brackets
# Please note: Adjusting manually as per p-values might be necessary
p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "kruskal.test", 
                       comparisons = list(c("0", "100"), c("0", "400"), c("100", "400")), 
                       label.y = c(350, 400, 475))


First you load the csv into DTdata but then you work with data?????

I have updated the DTData to data. But my issue still remains. I added the prism figure as well. "What values you you expecting?" I was expecting significant values for 0-100, 0-400 in each facet. I think it has something to do with zeros in my data but I'm not sure.

What do the asterisks mean in your expected results?  Do you know the values of the significances calculated by Prism?

I have added the values for significance in prism above - thank you

I think your problem is at least partially with the values that someone has calculated in Prism.  KW test is non-parametric, meaning that only the ranks of the data are considered, not the values themselves (so the fact that your error bars are small is irrelevant; you'd need to use a t-test or something similar to take these into account).  So the significances of 0 vs 100 and 0 vs 400 should be the same as each other in each case.  This isn't what's shown, suggesting that the KW test wasn't used (or wasn't used correctly...).

I think kruskal.test() takes x, g (values and group indicator) rather than x, y (values in two groups).  You'll need to wrap kruskal.test. Don't have time to show how to do that right now ...

You can calculate the correct values 'by hand' by putting the values in each group into a list.  So, for the third graph: kruskal.test(list(x[19:21,"CFUs"],x[22:24,"CFUs"]))$p.value and kruskal.test(list(x[19:21,"CFUs"],x[25:27,"CFUs"]))$p.value.  Both give the same p-value, 0.04953461.

This doesn't answer any questions about multiple comparisons corrections, but writing a kruskal.test() that takes x and y instead of x and g and passing it to the base-R kruskal.test appears to do what you want ...
kruskal.test <- function(x, y, paired = FALSE) {
    stats:::kruskal.test.default(x = c(x,y), g = rep(1:2, c(length(x), length(y))))
}
p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "kruskal.test", 
                       comparisons = list(c("0", "100"), c("0", "400"), c("100", "400"))) 


(from the comments: "non-significant" is rendered as NS. for p-values exactly equal to 1, ns otherwise)

Thank you for your help. Couple things. I found that "I also came across this problem. The string NS. is displayed for p-values equal to 1, the string ns in all other (non-significant) cases. While the latter is hidden when hide.ns = TRUE, the former is not." Credit to https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/171#issuecomment-621024736
Also in kruskal.test(CFUs ~ Treatment)$p.value); Things worked when I changed the ~ to a comma ,

I think that kruskal.test(CFUs, Treatment) might not be doing what you want/what you think ... !

Yes you are right. I get an error with your custom KW function. Can you take a look above? I entered the updated code and error I get Sorry for my newness.
